# Perfect when Adsense Tags are OFF

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm currenty working on a website optimization using Goole Pagespeed Insight recomendations. I've managed to get to a quite good score but I'm stuck at some point. After a few tests, my conclusion is that most of the last problems i have, are linked to the presence or not of Google Adsense tags in my pages.

My speed scores :

- Including Google Adsense tags (max 2 banners per page) :

  - 73 on mobile
  - 96 on desktop
- Without Google Adsense Tags :

  - 97 on mobile
  - 100 on desktop

Does anyone have any idea how to solve that problem ? (something smarter than "don't put adsense in your pages" ^^)
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.webnots.com/adsense-vs-page-speed-an-irony/

Above website wrote an article about how to optimize your page with AdSense.

I found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this LazyLoad AdSense:

Delete all your AdSense JS (that contains `https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js`), then put this code on footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> //<![CDATA[
var lazyadsense=!1;window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){(0!=document.documentElement.scrollTop&&!1===lazyadsense||0!=document.body.scrollTop&&!1===lazyadsense)&&(!function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(e,a)}(),lazyadsense=!0)},!0); 
//]]> </script>
```

This makes your ads will be loaded after the page is scrolled down.

Comment: Where is the client=ca-pub?

Comment: I have tried the code does not works